# How do I code a search query for a custom MaskedTextBox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

```
Using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-IIBSL6N;Initial Catalog=sales_management;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    SqlDataAdapter sqlad = new SqlDataAdapter("select * From Vehicle", sqlconn);
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    sqlad.Fill(dtbl);
    DataView dv = dtbl.DefaultView;
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Plate_Number like '%__ - _ - ___ - __%'", searchcompany.Text);
    vehiclegrid.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
}
```

I have problem with: `"Plate_Number like '%__ - _ - ___ - __%'"`

I don't know if it is correct for this: `00 - 000 - a - 00` custom format.
If it is correct, what can I do to search the column in the DataGridView which has the custom masked format?

Comment: Search the datatable the row in table will be same as row in DataView : dtbl.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Plate_Number").Contains("00 - 000 - a - 00").ToList();

Comment: are you looking for literal `_` character or should they match for example numbers, or letters

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani it isnt literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql accepts reqular expressions (but a bit limited) you can do something like:

```
Plate_Number like '%[0-9][0-9] - [0-9] - [0-9][0-9][0-9] - [0-9][0-9]%'
```

So:

```
SqlDataAdapter sqlad = new SqlDataAdapter("select * From Vehicle where Plate_Number like '%[0-9][0-9] - [0-9] - [0-9][0-9][0-9] - [0-9][0-9]%'", sqlconn);
```

Here is a [LIVE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b4f17d/1/0)

Comment: if i want one of these _ be letters what should i code instead of [0-9]?

Comment: [a-zA-Z] instead of [0-9]

Comment: I added a live dmo

Comment: since you are Persian [a-zA-Z] will this work for persian alphabets?

Comment: it should but to be honset i haven't checked persian regex in sql server

Comment: another question that i have is it normal to have multiple search textboxes one for each column in the datagridview that work together(connected together in searching columns) or each search textbox must work for itself

Comment: Error in Like operator: the string pattern '%[0-9][0-9] - [a-zA-Z] - [0-9][0-9][0-9] - [0-9][0-9]%' is invalid. i got this error where is the mistake?

Comment: the same works in the demo, please check maybe there is an error elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-IIBSL6N;Initial Catalog=sales_management;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            if(searchplate.MaskFull==true)
            {
                SqlDataAdapter sqlad = new SqlDataAdapter("select * From Vehicle  ", sqlconn);
                DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
                sqlad.Fill(dtbl);
                DataView dv = dtbl.DefaultView;
                dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Plate_Number like '%{0}%'", searchplate.Text);
                vehiclegrid.DataSource = dv.ToTable();  }
            }
```

The problem was that for maskedtextbox unlike normal textboxes you have to put condition for the search to work.